# Get the result from the use of a Google API

Tags: javascript, api, return

I would like the function timeZoneFix to return the variable timeFromLocation. The data is stuck in 
timeZoneAPI(...){...}. I want to get it out to be able to use it. I couldn't figure it out how to do this thanks!

```
function timeZoneFix(lat,lng,time){
    var locationInfo=[lat,lng,timeStamp/1000];
    timeZoneAPI(locationInfo,function(result){
    var timeFromLocation=[result.dstOffset,result.rawOffset];
    });
}

var timeZoneAPI = function(locationInfo,callback) {
  xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
  var url = buildUrl(locationInfo);
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var result = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    callback(result);
  };
  xhr.send();
};
```

Comment: The same way you do it with `timeZoneAPI`: You accept/pass a callback.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to do it. I am still trying but even with a callback I got "null"...

Comment: You do it exactly the same as with `timeZoneAPI`: Make `timeZoneFix` accept a callback. Inside `timeZoneFix`, call `callback(timeFromLocation);`, and call `timeZoneFix` as `timeZoneFix(lat, lng, time, function(result) { /* do something with the result */ });`. *Returning* the result from `timeZoneFix` is not possible.

Comment: So it is not possible to return a result from timeZoneFix! Thanks